# Failure @ Running Code through Normal Mode

Tags: excel, vba

My code properly works when I run it in Break Mode, but it doesn't works when I do a normal run!

Why?!

Here it is:

```
Sub ImportBHA()
   'Variables
    Dim Fullpath As String
    Dim oBHA As String 'Opened BHA
    Dim nRange As Integer 'Name Range
    Dim nRows As Integer 'Name Rows
    Dim SheetName As String 'Bitsheet Name
    Dim BookName As String 'Workbook Name


   'Initialization
    BookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the BHA Report"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx", 1
        .Show

        Fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

    If InStr(Fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

   'Open, Tab & Copy
    Workbooks.Open Fullpath
    oBHA = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    nRange = Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("C900").End(xlUp).Row

   'Create Temporary Worksheet
    'Workbooks(BookName).Sheets.Add(After:=Workbooks(BookName).Sheets(Workbooks(BookName).Sheets.Count)).Name = "Temp"

       'BHA Name
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("I4").Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ60").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

       'Tools Names
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("D9:D" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'nRows = Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65:AZ138").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange) Step 2
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools Serials
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("F9:F" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange) Step 2
            ActiveSheet.Range("J" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools Max OD
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("H9:H" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange) Step 2
            ActiveSheet.Range("N" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools OD/ID
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("G9:G" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange)
            ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools Gender
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("K9:K" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange)
            ActiveSheet.Range("S" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools Connection Size
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("I9:I" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange)
            ActiveSheet.Range("T" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools Connection Type
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("J9:J" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange)
            ActiveSheet.Range("W" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools Cum. Lengths
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("N9:N" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange)
            ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Tools Weights to Temp
        Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("O9:O" & nRange + 1).Copy
        Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For I = 65 To (65 + nRange)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & I) = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & I)
        Next I

       'Close BHA Sheet
        Workbooks(oBHA).Close savechanges:=False

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It is kinda long but it is "importing" data generated in an excel spreadsheet report by a Schlumberger proprietary software.

The code copies some values from the report sheet to he's own Bottom Hole Assembly sheet!

Comment: Care to share **what** doesn't work? Error? Unexpected output?

Comment: My guess is the problem is due to your use of `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet`. Will this always be ran from the same book?

Comment: I guess the Activewworkbook in break mode is not the same as in  normal code. Refer to the workbooks and worksheet in a correct way and your porblems might disappear.

Comment: Please read how to use [workbooks](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-workbook/) and [worksheets](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/)

Comment: @urdearboy It was expected to be data pasted on certain cells, but there is only empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you would start to modify your code to correctly refer to Workbooks & Worksheet objects.

`wb` = the sheet on your workbook where you will run the macro from
`ib` = the sheet on your import book where you will import values from

---

You will need to update the sheet name when setting `wb` to the sheet where your values will go. Right now, it is set at `Destination Sheet`.

Once you do this once, you only need to refer to `wb` and `ib` for the rest of your code. So when referring to a range on `ib` `BHARReport` sheet, just use `ib.Range("....")` and similarly for your main book, `wb.Range("....")`

---

For a specific example, you can reduce the below:

```
Workbooks(oBHA).Sheets("BHAReport").Range("D9:D" & nRange + 1).Copy
Workbooks(BookName).Worksheets(SheetName).Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

To:

```
ib.Range("D9:D" & LRow).Copy
wb.Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

resulting in **significantly** easier to follow code. This makes de-bugging code *much, much* easier as well since you can actually follow what is happening.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportBHA()

Dim wb As Worksheet, ib As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long, Fullpath as String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the BHA Report"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx", 1
    .Show
    Fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    If .SelectedItems.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
End With

'Make sure the sheet names are correct here
Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination Sheet")
Set ib = Workbooks.Open(Fullpath).Sheets("BHARReport")

LRow = ib.Range("C" & ib.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

wb.Range("Az60").Value = ib.Range("I4").Value

ib.Range("D9:D" & LRow).Copy
wb.Range("AZ65").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: I stopped before you starting using `Active` since I have no clue what sheet is active. If you follow the above method correctly, you will get desired result.